# Getting back to Brussels from Sint-Truiden with public transportation on a friday night

Tags: public-transport, belgium, brussels, sports-events

Too bad that Anderlecht is playing away the weekend when I visit Brussels (for the open source conference fosdem).
They play at Sint-Truiden on Friday night which isn't that far away from Brussels.

The game starts at 20.30 so it will end about 22.20.
A quick search reveals that there are no public transportation available after this point.

So my question is if this differs when there is a late soccer game? Will there be extra trains or buses to get back to Brussels?

Comment: If it's anything like the UK, lots of specialist transport will be put on. Try seeing if the club/any supporter groups have information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there will be no extra buses or train to return to Brussels. I wouldn't even make sense because the *combi-regeling* will be in effect. This means that all Anderlecht supporters must book there tickets through one of the official fan clubs and they must come with the bus of the fan club. They can not even enter the stadium if they would drive themselves. The people that return to Brussels after the match will invariably be Anderlecht supporters that will be on their charter bus and not on any public transportation.

So you have two options:

- Book bus and ticket through a fan club. A quick google gives you [a list](https://www.anderlecht-online.be/en/fanclubs). I have no idea it that is a complete list. The site is definitely not the official club website. Look for a fan club from the Brussels area, because all buses will obviously leave from where the club is based.
- Arrange your own transportation. Either you rent a car or carpool or something. Or you come back to Brussels the next morning when there are again trains after spending the night in Sint-Truiden. Up to you if you want to spend the whole night drinking or look for lodging in Sint-Truiden. If you go by yourself, make sure to [reserve your ticket beforehand](http://www.stvv.com/nl/tickets/tickets) because the ticket counters will be closed on match day. If you take this option, you will be among the Sint-Truiden supporters, so it is probably wise to leave anything purple in Brussels.